# Incompleteness of Lorentzian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $\tilde{M}$ be a simply connected Lorentzian manifold and suppose that $\tilde{M}$ admits some Riemannian metric.

Question: What can be said about the relation between the geodesic completeness of $\tilde{M}$ as a Lorentzian manifold and the metric completion as a metric space via the Riemannian metric? In particular, if $\tilde{M}$ is already metrically complete, is it then also Lorentzian geodesically complete?

Comment: You may find some interesting results in dimension two contained in [this](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Lorentz-Surfaces-Expositions-Mathematics/dp/311014333X) book by Tilla Weinstein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric (see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8/S0002-9939-1961-0133785-8.pdf)), you cannot deduce anything about the Lorentzian metric.

Even if every Riemannian metric on $\bar{M}$ is complete (so that $\bar{M}$ is necessarily compact), the Lorentzian metric may not be complete: the [Clifton-Pohl torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifton%E2%80%93Pohl_torus) is an example of a compact Lorentzian manifold which is not geodesically complete. This shows that the [Hopf-Rinow Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem) does not generalise to Lorentzian manifolds.

Comment: Yes I am well aware of these results. I am currently trying to understand that completeness is guaranteed when $M$ has constant sectional curvature and is compact. The [proof](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bruno.klingler/papiers/cvl.pdf) is rather complicated, and my question was conceptually relevant.